# Finding average between two dynamic range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, average

I have to find the average of a column B by giving a dynamic range for column A.

[image: input data]

I want to calculate the average by changing ranges from D2 & E2.

[image: Output data]

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: No i have some data in Column A i want to find the average of data in column B. So, i want to give two ranges in two cells and the formula i am looking for should result the average of column B by checking the range in Column A. Hope i am clear !!

Comment: So it **is** `AVERAGEIFS()` then =), see the answer below.

Comment: yes it is working. Thank you very much. Made my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `AVERAGEIFS()`:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">"&D2,A:A,"<="&E2)
```